# Definition of "simple" and "martial" weapons in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I can't seem to find a definition of what it is that makes a weapon "simple" or "martial". Obviously, I can look at the weapon tables and find out how each weapon is categorized. But what is the guiding principle between the distinction? Is it only a balancing mechanism?

For example: in what sense is a crossbow "simple" compared to the "martial" (= non-simple) bow? Intuitively, I would have expected bows to be labelled "simple", and the crossbow "non-simple".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple weapons require the least training to use correctly and effectively.  To use your example, I can hand an eight-year-old with no experience a crossbow, and within 10 minutes they can be reliably hitting a stationary target at close range.  It's just point-and-shoot.  The other weapons in the simple category include clubs and staves (literally, they're sticks - just pick them up off the ground and hit something with them), knives not much bigger than you'd use in a kitchen, spears (traditionally a weapon you can pass out a bunch of to a village to make an ad hoc military unit), and barehanded attacks.

The martial category includes weapons which are normally included in a professional warrior's training.  Bows (whose difficulty of use is a tradeoff for speed - I can personally assure you it's nowhere near as easy as media likes to make it look), swords, polearms (the ones that are more complicated than spears, anyway), and axes fill most of the category.  These weapons are too complicated for a random peasant to use effectively without training, but still normal enough to be included in a general fighting education.

You didn't exactly ask about exotic weapons, but since I'm here, it includes weapons that are unique, oversized, or non-intuitive enough in their use that even most trained professional soldiers aren't likely be able to use one effectively without special training or at least some time practicing with the weapon.  Double weapons are often exotic if there's even the slightest trick to using them.  Whips, mancatchers, and nets don't exactly act like other weapons.

All that said, there are some things that simply don't fit into Pathfinder's level of combat abstraction.  Other than reach and combat manuever weapons, the different weapons really don't do anything special to each other - and they really should, to be accurate.  A swordsman is generally much safer in a fight than an axeman, because his training with his sword lets him threaten foes that attack him with weapons like axes and kill them before the axe lands - you see that in media all the time, but not in Pathfinder (without special feats, anyway).  Game balance plays a small part - weapons with unique characteristics or combinations of desirable traits always seem to end up in the exotic category, like an 18-20 threat range coupled with a large damage die.  Some distinctions that should be made aren't - throwing a knife is *never* simple, except in Pathfinder - and some that probably shouldn't matter are - shuriken and chakram are basically identical but separated by a whole category here.

So, when it really boils down to it - game balance, ease of use, availability, and a decent degree of fiat on the part of the designers all go into weapon classification.  For your example specifically, though - a crossbow is MUCH, MUCH easier to use than a bow if you have no training.

Comment: Just to highlight what you already said: it's **simple *to use***, not simple to build.

Answer (score 8):

In theory, it’s supposed to be a combination of

1. How easy the weapon is to use (crossbows are not *quite* point-and-shoot, but they’re simpler than bows)
2. How familiar the weapon is to most characters in the setting (quarterstaves are fairly tricky, really, but as just a length of wood, it’s pretty likely that most characters have handled one before)
3. How good a weapon it is (martial weapons are frequently better than simple counterparts)

This is very much a subjective thing that Paizo (and Wizards of the Coast before them) made gut calls on. It is not particularly consistent or organized. Exotic weapons, in fact, are the most problematic; despite Exotic Weapon Proficiency being a special “thing” that most characters don’t have, they are mostly Exotic because they are “exotic” (read: Asian, or pure fantasy), neither necessarily being more difficult to use nor particularly better in any fashion.

Historically, this system originated in D&D 3.x, by Wizards of the Coast; Pathfinder is a variation on that system (since almost all of the system’s core mechanics were made Open Game Content by Wizards). Pathfinder changed nothing about the overall *concept*, and most of the simple and martial weapons are similarly unchanged (over time, both 3.5 and Pathfinder added weapons beyond those in core, and these differ between the two).

Exotic weapons, however, have changed. Originally, as in the D&D *Player’s Handbook*, exotic weapons came in one of two flavors: monk weapons, and superior weapons.

Many monk weapons were exotic without being better than their martial counterparts (the siangham, for instance, was *strictly worse* than the short sword); this was just a conceit to make the monk “different” even when one chose to use weapons rather than fight unarmed. They needed to be exotic so other martial classes wouldn’t have proficiency in them, but they didn’t need to be better because monks got free proficiency in them.

The other exotic weapons, though, were mostly unavailable to everyone unless you took a feat (Exotic Weapon Proficiency). Thus, they tended to be somehow “superior” to martial weapons in some fashion, usually in the form of a slightly-larger damage die when compared to a martial weapon with the same critical threat range or multiplier. There were a few exceptions to this, however: some weapons weren’t just slightly-better martial weapons, but somehow special: spiked chains and whips were reach weapons that could still attack adjacent squares, dwarven urgroshes and gnomish hook-hammers were double weapons that could switch up damage types based on the situation, nets and bolas tripped up enemies instead of damaging them, the whip was a one-handed reach weapon, the spiked chain was a two-handed finesse weapon.

This is important because the slightly-larger damage dice of most exotic weapons *was never worth a feat.* They tended to average approximately +1 damage, and even from the beginning you could do much better than that with a feat. But some of the special-use exotic weapons, most notably the spiked chain, *were* worth a feat. It’s important to note that even the best of these, the spiked chain, was never “must have,” since even in the beginning you could had alternative options for feats that made the cost of Exotic Weapon Proficiency very high (and as you added more supplements, the competition for that feat got more and more intense).

This was mostly a matter of the system being new and Wizards under- and over-estimating the value of various things. Later supplements would continue to add slightly-higher-damage exotic weapons, but over time more solid, special exotic weapons were printed. In other words, Wizards learned from its mistakes here and got better.

Unfortunately, Paizo took the opposite stance: that the few exotic weapons that were actually worth a feat, were overpowered because they were clearly better than other exotic *and martial* weapons. It was the opinion of Pathfinder’s lead developer that “just because it cost a feat,” read, a huge chunk of your character, didn’t mean that exotic weapons should be better than martial weapons, and voicing disagreement on this point was sufficient to get some users *banned* from the official Paizo forums. So, at this point, the Exotic Weapon Proficiency feat, in Pathfinder, exists solely to tax people who would like to use an unusual weapon; they will lose a feat in order to do so, but see no (significant) mechanical benefit.

Comment: The fact that this weapon system was "grandfathered in" from D&D 3.5e is pretty important. Pathfinder is an improved (obviously, that's subjective) version of D&D 3.5e, and as such most of the mechanics are either the same , modified, or have some kind of equivalent replacement, if the devs thought it should be reworked. In this case, the Simple/Martial weapon categories were directly ported over to PF with virtually no changes. The OP may find more useful information if they were to research why D&D has weapon categories as well.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc In terms of balance and mechanical design, Pathfinder is pretty objectively *worse* than 3.5. And exotic weapons *were* changed: where previously almost all made a nominal attempt to be worth a feat, and a few even were, Paizo nerfed the few that were and voicing the opinion that this was a mistake and that exotic weapons should be worth a feat has gotten people banned from their forums.

Comment: No worries, I'm aware of how lame Paizo is. I didn't mention Exotic weapons in my post though. I just wanted to say that this system originated in D&D in case OP was not aware, since the only part of any of these answers that reference that is the fact that WOTC is mentioned in yours.  I just wanted to be sure they looked down an avenue with more information on the topic if they wanted further research.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc ah fair point. I'll make that stand out more.

Answer (score 3):

The introductory part of the [Weapon Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#TOC-Weapon-Rules) explains the various groupings applicable to weapons (emphasis mine)

> Weapons are grouped into several interlocking sets of categories. These categories pertain to **what training is needed to become proficient in a weapon's use (simple, martial, or exotic)**, the weapon's usefulness either in close combat (melee) or at a distance (ranged, which includes both thrown and projectile weapons), its relative encumbrance (light, one-handed, or two-handed), and its size (Small, Medium, or Large).

The distinction is (intended to be) based on ease of use. For example, hitting someone over the head with a wooden club is <strike>easier</strike> more straightforward than wielding a longsword, which in turn is simpler than using Nunchaku. The same applies to crossbows vs. bows: Point and shoot is fairly easy compared to archery.